# get array of all json field keys in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called user, and inside the table there is a field called friends, this field is a json type has a value as in the following example

```
{"blockList": {"199": {"date": 1453197190, "status": 1}, "215": {"date": 1459325611, "status": 1}, "219": {"date": 1454244074, "status": 1}, "225": {"date": 1453981312, "status": 1}, "229": {"date": 1459327685, "status": 1}}, "followers": {"211": {"date": 1452503369}, "219": {"date": 1452764627}, "334": {"date": 1456396375}}, "following": {"215": {"date": 1459325619}, "219": {"date": 1453622322}, "226": {"date": 1454244887}, "229": {"date": 1459327691}}, "friendList": {"213": {"date": 1453622410, "type": 2, "status": 1}, "214": {"date": 1452763643, "status": 1}, "215": {"date": 1455606872, "type": 2, "status": 2}, "218": {"date": 1453280047, "status": 1}, "219": {"date": 1453291227, "status": 2}, "221": {"date": 1453622410, "type": 2, "status": 1}, "224": {"date": 1453380152, "type": 2, "status": 1}, "225": {"date": 1453709357, "type": 2, "status": 2}, "226": {"date": 1454244088, "type": 2, "status": 1}, "229": {"date": 1454326745, "type": 2, "status": 2}}}
```

this record has a blockList object that is containning objects for blocked users.
what I need, is to return an array of all block list keys like this

```
["199", "215", "219", "225", "229"]
```

any help how can I write a plpgsql function to do that (return all object keys in an array)?
I'm a beginner in psotgresql, and need a help please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`json_object_keys`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) to a set containing the outermost keys of a json object (so you'll need to select the object for the `blockList` key, which you can do with `friends->'blockList'`), and use [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) to aggregate them into an array:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(f) 
FROM (
  SELECT json_object_keys(friends->'blockList') f
  FROM users
) u;
┌───────────────────────┐
│       array_agg       │
├───────────────────────┤
│ {199,215,219,225,229} │
└───────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

---

**Note:**
If you're using the `jsonb` type (and not the `json` one) you'll need to use the json**b**_object_keys function.

Comment: ERROR:  function json_object_keys(jsonb) does not exist
LINE 4:   SELECT json_object_keys(friends->'blockList') f
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: If you're using `jsonb` then you'll need to use the `jsonb_object_keys` function.

Comment: Whoops I forgot array_agg, nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT array_agg(ks) FROM (
    SELECT json_object_keys(friends->'blockList') AS ks
    FROM users
) x`

I have created a SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd626b/1) to demonstrate.

Note: `user` is a reserved word, so I have called the table `users`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, but I would like to propose following way, borrowed from Erwin [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127230/88041):

```sql
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT json_object_keys(friends->'blockList')) FROM users;
```

Comment: This seems to be a better answer when you have to get other columns from the table.